# Linear Algebra Problem of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have 2 vectors, $C_1$ and $C_2$ of differing lengths. If I know the matrix $C_k$ for which each element i,j is the product of the ith element in $C_1$ and the jth element in $C_2$, is it possible to find $C_1$ and $C_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the vectors are not unique. There is one degree of freedom in your choice.

---

Given vectors $a = [a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]^T$ and $b = [b_1, b_2, ..., b_n]^T$ and a matrix $M=ab^T$ with entries $M_{i,j} = a_ib_j$, I can always set $a' = \alpha a$ and $b' = \frac{1}{\alpha}b$ and get the matrix $M'=a'b'^T$ with the same entries as $M$:

$$M'_{i,j} = a'_ib'_j = \alpha a_i \frac{1}{\alpha}b_j = a_i b_j = M_{i,j}$$

---

That said, given $M$ and just one (non-zero) component of $a$, the vectors $a$ and $b$ become unique.

Say we know $a_1$, then we know all of $b$ from $b_j = \frac{M_{1,j}}{a_1}$. From there, we know all of $a$ from $a_i = \frac{M_{i,2}}{b_2}$.